# XHTML strict span inside label is semantic

Tags: xhtml-1.0-strict

I'm using XHTML strict. I want to put a `SPAN` tag inside `LABEL` tag. Is it correct way?

```
<label>Username <span>*</span></label><input type="text" .... />
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`label` is an inline element therefore can contain other inline elements like `span`. So this is correct XHTML.

Comment: thnx !! will this make any accessibility problem ?

Comment: Would like to know this also