# Text-Display:none CSS? Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<label><input type="radio">TextmakesNoSense</label>
```

So this dynamically generated content is Read-Only... So I thought...

```
label {
    color:#fff;
    font-size:0.0001em;
}
```

on a webpage with a white background, however seems very sneeky to me and if you highlight the buttons you can still see there is text there, on some browsers anyways.

So u think a new version of CSS would include "text-display:none;" ?

I could insert some jquery instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put a `span` tag around it:

```
<label><input type="radio"><span class="ro-text">TextmakesNoSense</span></label>
```

CSS:

```
.ro-text {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Or

```
.ro-text {
    display: none;
}
```

Depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

If you need to add the span dynamically, use this jQuery:

```
$('label').html($('label').find('input')[0].outerHTML + '<span class="ro-text">'+$('label').text()+'</span>');
```

For a quick explanation of what

http://jsfiddle.net/Cwalkdawg/h5kYQ/2/

A `span` inside a `label` is ["semantic"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657629/xhtml-strict-span-inside-label-is-sementic) in case you were worried.

Comment: I'm going to give you props for simply making a working jfiddle.  I have no idea why it looks like an intentional syntax error on col 127 (after text()) however I dont know jquery that well and its working on your jfiddle.  Direct pasting of this code does not work on my page for some reason.. I'll keep playing with this it seems to be the cleanest option.  I'm just trying to accomplish "no display" for the text that I dont want to display.

Comment: Just to reply to Kolink - I liked your answer too, however just because the file is Read Only doesn't mean I can't edit the DOM with jQuery.

Comment: @AndrewDurocher, it was a syntax error that I forgot to update. I updated the jsFiddle and the answer! Sorry about that.

Answer (score 6):

Try `text-indent:-9999px`. This should move the text far off to the left so it's off the screen.

Comment: This doesn't bode well for screenreaders if it is just nonsensical content.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
label {
    color:#fff;
    font-size:0.0001em;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use this method when I have text to hide.

```
.label {
    text-indent: 150%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 0.0001em
}
```

**General Advantages:**
Really long strings of text will never flow into the container because they always flow away from the container.

**Advantages over the common -9999px method:**
Performance is dramatically improved because a 9999px box is not drawn. (Yes, the browser really does draw a huge box of to the side.)

References:
[Website Article](http://www.zeldman.com/2012/03/01/replacing-the-9999px-hack-new-image-replacement/)

Answer (score 0):

```
font-size:0px;
```

That seems to do the trick, not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Fails in Chrome, where the default configuration is that the minimum allowable `font-size` is 6pt.

Comment: I wrote this in chrome using conceptfactory.co.nz/editor.html

If it isn't allowed, then I don't know why it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, may be it will solve your problem.

```
label {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As written above `font-size:0` is one of options. But sometimes it's messing with dimensions or size of text-container. I'm using another trick which doesn't change anything except text, just setting font color with alpha channel - 0.

```
.label{
color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```